# Magento2: Disable user from changing addresses

Tags: customer, address, magento2.2

Is there a way to **disable customers from adding, editing, or deleting addresses** on their account? I want to be able for users to add the address during registration and **then after the account is created, changes can** only be made from the backend or rest API. Customers can view the address book but not make any changes themselves. We are using Magento 2.2.0.

Comment: what about check new address create and save?

Comment: I'm sorry can  you explain?

Comment: except the   customer address page, Magento also add new address of a customer at checkout page.So, My question is that are you to prevent to  address from Also Checkout?

Comment: Yes, I want to make it impossible for a customer to add, update or delete an address. This includes preventing them from changing from their account page and the checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

A solution will be to customize the address `book.phtml` template by removing the links to edit and add addresses.

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\address\book.phtml
```